# Can subsequences be finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Say I'm given the sequence $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$. Does a subsequence **have** to be infinite? Or can it be finite too? For example, is $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ a subsequence?

Comment: It depends on the context.

Answer (score 9):

Yes the subsequence must be infinite. Any subsequence is itself a sequence, and a sequence is basically a function from the naturals to the reals.

Comment: Wholeheartedly disagreed.  Without more specification, a sequence is simply a function from _some well-ordered set_ to the range of the sequence.  $\omega$ (or $\mathbb{N}$, if you prefer) is one such well-ordered set, but transfinite sequences are often spoken of and finite sequences aren't at all uncommon.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, this is the definition of subsequence.

**Definition.** Let $\{p_n\}_n$ be a sequence (in some set), and let $n_1<n_2<n_3<\ldots$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers. Then the sequence $\{p_{n_j}\}_j$ is called a subsequence of $\{p_n\}_n$.

It follows that $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is not a subsequence of $\{p_n\}_n$, since $n_1=1$, $n_2=2$, $n_3=3$, but what is $n_4$? This is the common feeling for mathematical analysts.

However, we must be careful, since it all boils down to the very definition of *sequence*. In analysis, a sequence is a function $\mathbb{N} \to X$, or, more generally, a function $N \to X$, where $N \subset \mathbb{N}$ is such that $N$ contains all sufficiently large integers.
In other disciplines, it might be useful to call sequence any function defined on a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, even a finite one.

Answer (score 3):

A sequence in a set $X$ is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$. Let $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a strictly increasing sequence, then the composition of $f$ and $g$, is called a subsequence of $f$. Thus the *domain* of a subsequence is always infinite, but the *range* can certainly be finite.

As an example consider the sequence $f(n):=n$ even $n$ and $f(n):=1$ odd $n$.  Let $g(n):=2n+1$. The range of $f\circ g$ is equal to $\{1\}$, which is finite.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the term *subsequence* has always referred to an infinite subsequence. I believe this is standard. If you want to consider finite subsequences, you should say *finite subsequence*, or if you want to consider subsequences that may or may not be finite, you can say *possibly finite subsequence*.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence (real, sets, etc...) is simply a list. In mathematics, unless specified, a finite list (i.e. sequence) is not denoted to be a sequence. A sequence MUST continue unimpeded.

By definition, a sequence of real numbers is a mapping from N -> R. The nature of this definition demonstrates that a finite sequence cannot exist under our current consideration.